# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse and tomcat however WAR is working in standalone tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, deployment, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to deploy maven generated war file into tomcat server in eclipse.. but I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on a jar file. I verified multiple times, jar is in .war and corresponding class file is also available in jar.
I can copy the war from generated location in eclipse and deploy into webapps of tomcat (using the same server as installed server in eclipse) successfully.

I am not sure what else to check in configuration apart from deployment assembly (which has jar listed) and Java Build path ( jar is available in Maven Dependencies). I am using JRE --> Alternate JRE pointing to JDK 1.6

Complete ERROR LOG:

```
2012-05-24 16:43:09,379 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader -       Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/att/cso/uss/client/ws/CciClientImpl;

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.att.cso.uss.client.ws.CciClientImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    ... 33 more
```

Please advise.

Comment: How about giving more details of your eclipse setup?  Do you use m2e and if so m2e-wtp?  Eclipse does not use the `war` file created in `target` folder of maven to deploy to tomcat.

Comment: How are you deploying the war within eclipse? Did you add the maven source project to the tomcat server instance in Servers view?

Comment: @Raghuram - I am using m2e-wtp. So where and how I can look for deployment war in eclipse. Does any file in settings folder need to be verified ?

Comment: @Ravi - Yes.. in server instance (view) of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Using server instance is not same as deploying WAR in tomcat. The servers view integration of tomcat 'hot' deploys the source folder. I suggest you check you Java Build path settings because those are used when you 'deploy' the source project into the server in servers view. How are you creating the war? I am assuming you are using maven for it..  If you are using maven (I have personal dislike for it), it should be managing the dependencies for you. You might have to replicate settings of maven in java or may be use maven plugin for eclipse. [http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/]

Comment: I am using maven and m2e/m2e-wtp plugin. In the build path of project, I have Maven Dependencies which got all jars (including the jar that is having the issue as in logs seen in my question). Deploying project (mainweb) having a dependency on jar (cciclient). Should I link the source of ccliClient project in the build path of mainweb ??

Comment: I'm not sure what ccliClient means. But if it is either a build time or a runtime dependency you should be adding it to your project dependencies. Build time means, you need it for compilation. Runtime means you need it runtime (Usually the dependency would be via reflection)

Comment: check this question if the JAR file was included as a system scope dependency - this is a possible cause of NoClassDefFoundError https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935135/maven-and-adding-jars-to-system-scope