# Maven and adding JARs to system scope

Tags: maven

I have a JAR in my Android project and I want it to be added to final APK.
Okay, here I go:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.loopj.android.http</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-async-http</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/android-async-http-1.3.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But when I am running `mvn package` I am getting a warning:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for **apk:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.loopj.android.http:android-async-http:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/libs/android-async-http-1.3.2.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 36, column 25
```

And in the final APK there are no JARs.

How do I fix that?

Comment: You can't use system scope this way. use install:install-file.

Comment: @bmargulies Can you say what is this scope for?

Comment: I switched to gradle and don't have these headaches anymore except now I am trying to use an open source library with maven and temporarily hack a jar in(which is this so easy in gradle and so hard in maven).

Comment: This question has discussion of how to avoid using system scope in Maven: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642023/having-a-3rd-party-jar-included-in-maven-shaded-jar-without-adding-it-to-local-r

Comment: Official documentation about the scope 'system' : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

Comment: Nice solution here: https://gist.github.com/timmolderez/92bea7cc90201cd3273a07cf21d119eb

Comment: v2.5.3 will use the POM inside the jar if is has it, so you can just point mvn to the .jar and it will do the rest.  See  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: even though the question is pretty old, I think it's worth mentioning for those interested, that system scope is deprecated [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will need to [add the jar](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to your local maven repository.  Alternatively (better option) specify the proper repository (if one exists) so it can be automatically downloaded by maven

In either case, remove the `<systemPath>` tag from the dependency

Comment: I've seen that article but I hoped not to do `maven install` on every computer where I want to build that project (unfortunately I not found this JAR in repos). Thanks! :)

Comment: It can be scripted as part of the build.

Answer (score 156):

I don't know the real reason but Maven pushes developers to install all libraries (custom too) into some maven repositories, so `scope:system` is not well liked, A simple workaround is to use `maven-install-plugin`

**follow the usage:**

write your dependency in this way

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mylib</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

then, add maven-install-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-external</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/lib/mylib-core-0.0.1.jar</file>
                <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>com.mylib</groupId>
                <artifactId>mylib-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

pay attention to `phase:clean`, to install your custom library into your repository, you have to run `mvn clean` and then `mvn install`

Comment: Why not use `<phase>process-resources</phase>` instead of `<phase>clean</phase>`. The process-resources phase looks more appropriate for such a scenario and it is always called before the compile phase.

Comment: in a first installation, are you sure you can pass 'validate' phase which comes before of process-resources in 'built lifecycle' ? ; ), 'clean lifecycle' comes first 'built lifecycle' and it hasn't dependecies with any validation, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_life_cycle.htm

Comment: It works, but how do you install several dependencies?

Comment: @RenaudPawlak Use multiple `<execution></execution>`?

Comment: Stackoverflow should add a feature that allows community to override OP's choice of correct answer, because IMHO, This answer should be the accepted one! :)

Comment: As others have commented, binding to `clean` phase is very misleading, it's not part of the default lifecycle, and distorts the meaning of  `clean`.  
  
Furthermore, the suggested change to use a phase in the default lifecycle (e.g. `validate` or `process-resources`) will fail in a multi-module situation, as dependency resolution is attempted by the aggregator, _prior_ to any custom goals executing for child modules.

Comment: can I add a folder instead of a single jar here?

Comment: in my case neither clean or process-resources worked. my netbeans wouldn't execute the plugin. setting phase to initialize and running mvn initialize, prior to build, only worked.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366787/maven-install-external-jar-through-pom-not-working

Comment: As per many posts this solution is not the recommended one, one it works. Was stuck on this and tried many things, but this worked.. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 11):

System scope was only designed to deal with 'system' files; files sitting in some fixed location. Files in `/usr/lib`, or `${java.home}` (e.g. `tools.jar`). It wasn't designed to support miscellaneous `.jar` files in your project.

The authors intentionally refused to make the pathname expansions work right for that to discourage you. As a result, in the short term you can use `install:install-file` to install into the local repo, and then some day use a repo manager to share.

Answer (score 4):

Try this configuration. It worked for me:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>mywebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
        <warSourceExcludes>source\**,build\**,dist\**,WEB-INF\lib\*,
            WEB-INF\classes\**,build.*
        </warSourceExcludes>
        <webXml>myproject/source/deploiement/web.xml</webXml>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>mywebRoot/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                <includes>
                        <include>mySystemJar1.jar.jar</include>
                         <include>mySystemJar2.jar</include>
                   </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a repository manager and install this kind of jars into it. That solves your problems at all and for all computers in your network.

Comment: We planned to run a repo on local server tomorrow or after tomorrow but before that I should solve this problem some other way.

Comment: As @efpies mentioned this may be a pie-in-the-sky answer when a developer does not have permissions/ability to create repo manager.

Comment: These days, if you have docker installed all you need is `docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3` -- see https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.paic.maven -DartifactId=tplconfig-maven-plugin -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tplconfig-maven-plugin-1.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true

Install the jar to local repository.

Comment: This is cumbersome than adding through the pom directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ging3r i got solution:

follow these steps:

1. don't use  in dependency tag. Use following in dependencies tag in pom.xml file::

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netsuite.suitetalk.proxy.v2019_1</groupId>
            <artifactId>suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2019_1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netsuite.suitetalk.client.v2019_1</groupId>
            <artifactId>suitetalk-client-v2019_1</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netsuite.suitetalk.client.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>suitetalk-client-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

 2. use following code in plugins tag in pom.xml file:


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>suitetalk-proxy</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${basedir}/lib/suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2019_1-1.0.0.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.netsuite.suitetalk.proxy.v2019_1</groupId>
                            <artifactId>suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2019_1</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>suitetalk-client</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${basedir}/lib/suitetalk-client-v2019_1-2.0.0.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.netsuite.suitetalk.client.v2019_1</groupId>
                            <artifactId>suitetalk-client-v2019_1</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>suitetalk-client-common</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${basedir}/lib/suitetalk-client-common-1.0.0.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.netsuite.suitetalk.client.common</groupId>
                            <artifactId>suitetalk-client-common</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

I am including 3 jars from lib folder:

[![including external jar in spring boot project][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWDmP.png


Finally, use `mvn clean` and then `mvn install` or 'mvn clean install' and just run jar file from target folder or the path where install(see `mvn install` log):

`java -jar abc.jar`

note: Remember one thing if you are working at jenkins then first use `mvn clean` and then `mvn clean install` command work for you because with previous code `mvn clean install` command store cache for dependency.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this thread I was able to configure the install plugin to load my custom jar, but the plugin was not seeing my `configuration` when running a `mvn install`

I'm using the base `maven-install-plugin:2.5.2` using the `maven:3.6.3-jdk-8` docker image.

I don't fully understand [this note in the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) (at the end of the section), but it seems that you can give the phase goal an execution id forcing it to use your configuration:

> Note: Configurations inside the  element used to differ from those that are outside  in that they could not be used from a direct command line invocation because they were only applied when the lifecycle phase they were bound to was invoked. So you had to move a configuration section outside of the executions section to apply it globally to all invocations of the plugin. Since Maven 3.3.1 this is not the case anymore as you can specify on the command line the execution id for direct plugin goal invocation. Hence if you want to run the above plugin and it's specific execution1's configuration from the command-line, you can execute:

> `mvn myqyeryplugin:queryMojo@execution1`

My final working docker command:

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name parser -v "$(shell pwd)":/usr/src/parser -w /usr/src/parser maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 mvn -X install:install-file@install-my-jar-file
```

Where `install-my-jar-file` is my executions id `<execution><id>install-my-jar-file</id>...`