# Cannot load netezza JDBC driver

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have configured a netezza db in spring . I have added the dependent nzjdbc.jar in the classpath

Spring config:

```
<bean id="QA_CAM_BASE_jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
```

```
    <!-- Initialization for data source -->

<bean id="QA_CAM_BASE_dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${com.ec.database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${com.ec.database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${com.ec.database.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${com.ec.database.pass}"/>
```

```
pom xml config 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netezza</groupId>
    <artifactId>netezza</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/nzjdbc.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

<resource> 
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib</directory> 
    <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath> 
</resource> 
</webResources>
```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.netezza.Driver]

Comment: `system` scoped jars aren't packaged in your jar. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935135/maven-and-adding-jars-to-system-scope

Comment: Got your point but i copy it manually while packaging war using the resources tag

Comment: No you aren't... You are only specifying a path you aren't copying anything with that. You would need a modified config of the war-plugin for that.

Comment: Where can i download  the  nzjdbc.jar   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `nzjdbc.jar` in your local maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=netezza.jar -DgroupId=org.netezza -DartifactId=netezza -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

(execute this in the directory where the `netezza.jar` is located

And then use it like a normal dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netezza</groupId>
    <artifactId>netezza</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

@See [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)