# Failed connection to Netezza with Java JDBC squirrel-sql driver

Tags: java, jdbc, netezza, squirrel-sql

I was trying to build a simple java application which will create a connection to netezza server with Java JDBC

I failed to find the jar of  `org.netezza.Driver` on `google` and on `maven` repository and also on `http://www.java2s.com/`

So i tried to use `squirrel-sql`

This is my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.squirrel-sql.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>netezza</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.netezza.NetezzaPlugin");
        System.out.println("Start");
        Connection ct = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:netezza://anyname-this-is.server.uk.ibm.com:5480/BACC_PRD_IDM_ACS", "cgclem", "@23634snkln");
        System.out.println("Connected");
}
```

The error attached here:

```
    Start
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:netezza://*********************************
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.zzz.ppp.DatabaseProvider.main(DatabaseProvider.java:368)
```

Comment: That dependency is not a JDBC driver, it is a plugin for the Squirrel SQL query tool.

Comment: Where can I find JDBC driver for netezza ?

Comment: No idea, you need to google it. Asking to find external resources is off-topic.

Comment: even google didnt find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netezza being a commercial product, the JDBC driver (contained in `nzjdbc.jar`) is supposedly not available on the internet. If your company uses a Netezza appliance, then you ought to be able to get that driver either from someone inside your company, or from IBM given you provide some evidence that your company is indeed using an appliance.

Once you get a hand on `nzjdbc.jar`, you will have to install it manually to your Maven repository for the same reasons. You can follow the instructions given on this other SO post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31531394/5751783